# Angular JS - Dynamic URL for $http get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to do a login for my app, using a rest api I designed. If I force the complete URL with the user and the pass It works alright:

```
http://www.myexample.com/ACTION/USER/PASSWORD/
```

But I need to take the data from the input fields of my form. This is code of the function in my controller:

```
$scope.authenticar = function(selectedUs, selectedPw){
  $scope.remoteData = null;
  //alert(selectedUs);
  dataService.getData(function(data) {
    $scope.resultAPI = data;
    $scope.username=$scope.resultAPI.username;
    $scope.id_user=$scope.resultAPI.id_user;
    $scope.isauthenticated=$scope.resultAPI.isauthenticated;
    $scope.user_role=$scope.resultAPI.user_role;
    $scope.complete_name=$scope.resultAPI.complete_name;
  });
}
```

And this is the service code:

```
.service('dataService', function($http) {
   delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

   this.getData = function(callback) {
     var myparams = {a: '', u: '', p: ''};
     myparams.a = 'ZW50cmFy';
     myparams.u = 'anRk';
     myparams.p = '899960d8dd39b29e790845912cb35d96';
     $http({
       method: 'GET',
       url: 'http://www.adagal.net/api_adagal/api.php',
       withCredentials: false,
       params: myparams,
       headers: {
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
       }
    }).success(function(data, status, header, config){
    // With the data succesfully returned, call our callback
       callback(data);
    }).error(function(){
       $scope.remoteData = null;
       return "Connection Error";
    });
  }
});
```

I tried to pass all the ways, how can I get the URL this way?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do here. It sounds as though you want to pass a dynamic string to the $http hashes url param? Is that true? What's your problem in this case?

Comment: True, I am trying to pass a dynamic string to $http. My problem is the if I pass the parameters to the function, something like this:
    this.getData = function(callback, p, u) {
It dont works, dont pass the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to do here, you want to pass username and password by url? or post/get data?

Either way you'll need to pass the username and password into the service. You can do that by passing it in the service function.

```
this.getData = function(username, password, callback) {
    ...
  })...
}
```

On the calling side:

```
dataService.getData($scope.username, $scope.password, function(){...});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you should change your service like this:

```
  .service('dataService', function($http) {
   delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    this.getData = function(URL, callback) {
     var myparams = {a: '', u: '', p: ''};
     myparams.a = 'ZW50cmFy';
     myparams.u = 'anRk';
     myparams.p = '899960d8dd39b29e790845912cb35d96';
     $http({
       method: 'GET',
       url: URL,
       withCredentials: false,
       params: myparams,
       headers: {
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
       }
    }).success(function(data, status, header, config){
    // With the data succesfully returned, call our callback
       callback(data);
    }).error(function(){
       $scope.remoteData = null;
       return "Connection Error";
    });
  }
});
```

And then call it like this:

```
  var url = "http://wwwmyexample.com/ACTION/"  + $scope.selectedUs + "/" + $scope.selectedPw + "/"
  dataService.getData(url, function(data) {
  $scope.resultAPI = data;
  $scope.username=$scope.resultAPI.username;
  $scope.id_user=$scope.resultAPI.id_user;
  $scope.isauthenticated=$scope.resultAPI.isauthenticated;
  $scope.user_role=$scope.resultAPI.user_role;
  $scope.complete_name=$scope.resultAPI.complete_name;
});
```

And in HTML you should have smth like this:

```
<input ng-model="selectedUs" />
<input ng-model="selectedPw" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the answers. I found my error:

```
 dataService.getData(function(u, p, data) {
```

And here was my error

```
 dataService.getData(u, p, function(data) {
```

I was putting u and p beside data, unforgivable error. Thank you all for the help.